# Using Windows key as meta for emacs via putty (windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, emacs, putty

In my .emacs file, I have included the following line:

```
(setq x-super-keysym 'meta)
```

However, when I run emacs and attempt to type M-x by hitting Win+X, Windows 7 interprets the keystrokes and opens windows mobility center.

Am I stuck using either Esc or Alt as meta? Or is there a way to get the Win key through putty to emacs?

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to use Win as Meta, I would suggest you to remap your keyboard using [sharpkeys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/), or autohotkey.